# Laravel controller function applied globally

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller for my website's inbox page, and in this controller there is a function that counts the number of unread messages the user has.

```
    public function updateUnreadCount() {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $value = 0;
            $messages = Message::where(function($query) {
                return $query->where('recipient_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('reci_read', 0)
                ->orWhere('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('sender_read', 0);
            }); 

            foreach ($messages as &$value) {
                    ++$value;
            };

            Auth::user()->update([
                'unread_msg' => $value,
            ]);
        };  
    }
```

What I'd like to know is, how could I make this function trigger globally for all authenticated users, so that I could display the number of unread message on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers)

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered.

Say your unread inbox is located in `navbar.blade.php`.

```
        // From the documentation, using Closure based composers...
        View::composer('navbar', function ($view) {
            if(Auth::user()) {
              //logic here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

refer http://culttt.com/2014/02/10/using-view-composers-laravel-4/

A View Composer is essentially just a piece of code that is executed and bound to a View whenever that View is requested.

For multiple pages 
You can also make this data available on multiple pages by adding a comma separated listed of Views.

```
View::composer(array('profile','dashboard'), function($view)
{
  $view->with('count', Unread::updateUnreadCount());
});
```